# Is there any way to retrieve Amazon product code?

Tags: asp.net, api, amazon-product-api

I am trying to display the amazon products of a specific category on my website using amazon product advertising api.
I am writing code is asp.net.
I am being able to successfully retrieve its price, title,image,url.I also want to get its product id that amazon uses.I had a look at its documentation in which they had mentioned something about the UPC(universal product code) and ASIN.But they have explained look up search based on UPC and ASIN.
I am too confused as to how to get its product id.

```
String requestString ="Service=AWSECommerceService"
               + "&Version=2013-29-03"
               + "&Operation=ItemSearch"
               + "&AssociateTag=myassociatetag"
               + "&SearchIndex=" +category
               + "&ItemPage=5"
               + "&Sort=relevancerank"
               + "&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes,Images"
               + "&Keywords=" + keyword
               + "&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]"
               ;
```

Can you please help me and tell me where to add itemid in this requeststring.
Thank you .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's no reason to SHOUT here. We can all read quite well (if we couldn't, we wouldn't be here), and YELLING AT US won't get you help any faster. (Besides, it's quite rude.) There's also no need to put information in your question title that's available in the tags; the tag system works very efficiently here, and it doesn't need any help.

Comment: I am sorry.I was not aware about it.I will make sure that this will not be repeated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the response group "ItemIds" to retrieve "ASIN" into your request parameter

- "&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes,Images,ItemIds"

UPC is returned by "ItemAttributes" response group which is already in your code.it will only return UPC if it exists in Amazon Database.